# Left join with nested selects and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, aggregate-functions

#### Problem

I have one table of generated dates (s) which I want to join with another table (d) which is a list of dates where a specific occurrence has happened.

**table `s`**

```
Wednesday 23rd August 2017
Thursday 24th August 2017
Friday 25th August 2017
Saturday 26th August 2017
```

**table `d`**

```
day_created -------------------------------- count
Thursday 24th August 2017 ----------------    45 
Saturday 26th August 2017 ----------------    32
```

I want to show rows where the occurrence does not take place, which I cannot do if I just have table d.

**I want something that looks like:**

```
day_created -------------------------------- count
Wednesday 23rd August  ---------------------  0
Thursday 24th August 2017  ----------------  45 
Friday 25th August 2017  ------------------   0
Saturday 26th August 2017 ----------------   32
```

I've tried joining with a left join as follows:

```
SELECT day_created, COUNT(d.day_created) as total_per_day
FROM 
(SELECT date_trunc('day', task_1.created_at) as day_created
FROM task_1
)
d
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT (generate_series('2017-05-01', current_date, '1 day'::INTERVAL)) as standard_date
)
s
ON d.day_created=s.standard_date
GROUP BY d.day_created
ORDER BY day_created DESC;
```

I don't get an error however the join isn't working (i.e. it doesn't return dates where the count is null). What it returns is the dates from table d and the count, but not the dates in between where there are 0 occurrences.

I've been going round in circles and have understood that I need to make table `s` (I think!) the left table, but I'm getting confused as a newbie with the syntax.

This is all in PostgreSQL 9.5.8.

Comment: Add calendar table in your database. That is good option instead of making date table in query.

Comment: You need the outer join in the opposite direction. Either swap the table position in your `from ... left join` clause, or use `right join` instead of `left join`.

Comment: have done so.

Gave the right join a go, however it's not returning the right thing. I think the first solution would work, but am getting stuck with the syntax when swapping the table position.

Comment: I kindly asked under your last question to disclose your Postgres version. Run `SELECT version()` if you are not sure. And proper table definitions showing data types and constraints.

Comment: In the table description you speak of a count column, but you don't use it in your query. Do you want to sum or count?

Comment: i want to count

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter this is the version im on: PostgreSQL 9.5.8

Comment: Thanks - very new to this, your answer below worked nicely. Have now accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you had the `LEFT JOIN` backwards. This should work, with some other simplifications and performance optimizations:

```
SELECT s.standard_date, COUNT(d.day_created) AS total_per_day
FROM   generate_series('2017-05-01', current_date, interval '1 day') s(standard_date)
LEFT   JOIN task_1 d ON d.day_created >= s.standard_date
                    AND d.day_created <  s.standard_date + interval '1 day'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This *counts* rows in `d`, like you commented. Does not *sum* values.

Be aware that `generate_series()` still returns `timestamp with time zone`, even if you pass `date` values to it. You may want to cast to `date` or format with `to_char()` for display in the outer `SELECT`. (But rather group and order by the original timestamp *value*, not the formatted string.)

There may be corner cases depending on the current time zone setting depending on the actual undisclosed table definition.

Related:

- [How to avoid a subquery in FILTER clause?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179629/how-to-avoid-a-subquery-in-filter-clause/179861#179861)

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well, and the explanation is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

> I have one table of generated dates (s)

In real databases, we don't store a generated series. We just generate them when needed.

> which I want to join with another table (d) which is a list of dates where a specific occurrence has happened. [...] **I want to show rows where the occurrence does not take place, which I cannot do if I just have table d.**

Nah, you can do it.

```
CREATE TABLE d(day_created, count) AS VALUES
  ('24 August 2017'::date, 45),
  ('26 August 2017'::date, 32);

SELECT day_created, coalesce(count,0)
FROM (
  SELECT d::date
  FROM generate_series(
    '2017-08-01'::timestamp without time zone,
    '2017-09-01'::timestamp without time zone,
    '1 day'
  ) AS gs(d)
) AS gs(day_created)
LEFT OUTER JOIN d USING(day_created)
ORDER BY day_created;

 day_created | coalesce 
-------------+----------
 2017-08-01  |        0
 2017-08-02  |        0
 2017-08-03  |        0
 2017-08-04  |        0
 2017-08-05  |        0
 2017-08-06  |        0
 2017-08-07  |        0
 2017-08-08  |        0
 2017-08-09  |        0
 2017-08-10  |        0
 2017-08-11  |        0
 2017-08-12  |        0
 2017-08-13  |        0
 2017-08-14  |        0
 2017-08-15  |        0
 2017-08-16  |        0
 2017-08-17  |        0
 2017-08-18  |        0
 2017-08-19  |        0
 2017-08-20  |        0
 2017-08-21  |        0
 2017-08-22  |        0
 2017-08-23  |        0
 2017-08-24  |       45
 2017-08-25  |        0
 2017-08-26  |       32
 2017-08-27  |        0
 2017-08-28  |        0
 2017-08-29  |        0
 2017-08-30  |        0
 2017-08-31  |        0
 2017-09-01  |        0
(32 rows)
```